# How do I fix private policy issue and family policy requirement for app to be published in google play store?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, app-store, privacy-policy

My application was rejected for not being compliant with user data policy. The website I linked was [this page](https://www.privacypolicies.com/blog/mobile-apps-privacy-policy/) which is just some random page I found on the internet that states privacy policies. It states that I need to have my privacy policy page must be linked on my store listing page and within my app itself? What do they mean by store listing page? I haven't published any apps ever so what do they mean by store listing page? It also states that I need to have an active visible URL, do I need to buy a domain for this? Does anyone know any websites that can create a valid URL for me for my privacy policy page or do I need to buy a domain and create my own privacy policy website from sratch?

My app also got rejected regarding the families policy requirements.My app is a calculator application. I checked in every age group as I want my app to have the largest audience possible, is my type of app not allowed for certain ages? Also for ads, what code is required to be in my app in order for it to be suitable for kids and all ages, do I need any special permissions in my code? What settings do I need to set in admob for my ads to be suitable for kids? I have already read the policies for these two problems I had but I am still confused on what to do on these certain problems I am having.

Comment: This question isn't suitable for this site. Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic to understand why not.

Comment: I am driving at the moment but I will post an answer shortly. I can explain admob and the new requirements, as well as everything you asked

Comment: Can I at least get an opinion based answer, that would help a lot.